# How to use jQuery to select IDs not in specific class

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a jQuery script that selects all IDs with 'Phone' in them. However, I have a small part that needs to NOT select them if they are in a class.

What I have, according to the way I understand it is this:

```
$("[id*='Phone']:not('referencePhones')").doSomething();
```

What am I missing?

.referencePhones is a parent class. ie:

```
div class="referencePhones"
  span id="Phone"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("[id*='Phone']").parent(":not('.referencePhones')").css("color","red");
```

and your code looks something like the following right?

```
<div class="referencePhones">
  <span id="Phone2">phone2</span>
  <span id="Phone3">phone3</span>
  <span id="Phone4">phone4</span>
  <span id="Phone5">phone5</span>      
</div>

<div class="zzz">
  <span id="Phone6">phone6</span>
  <span id="Phone7">phone7</span>
  <span id="Phone8">phone8</span>
  <span id="Phone9">phone9</span>      
</div>
```

Comment: i know you accepted this answer, and while it "works" it is not the best solution. i'm not trying to play sour grapes, but my solution is a lot faster because it will only search for `spans` with the id of phone rather than every single element on the page, as this solution will. just saying.

Answer (score 9):

get rid of your internal quotes:

```
$('someElement[id*=Phone]:not(.referencePhones)').doSomething();
```

**EDIT**

```
$('span[id*=Phone]').parent('div:not(.referencePhones)').doSomething();
```

Comment: you have to use the filter() together with is(!referencePhones); when i will have a moment ill write you the selector

Comment: I thought I was being perfectly clear, so much for thinking. Think it's time for me to pick up the jQuery in Action book!

Answer (score 4):

A dot?

```
$("[id*='Phone']:not(.referencePhones)").doSomething();
                     ^
```

Comment: Nope. Tried that. That class is a parent. .referencePhones #Phones

Answer (score 0):

The OP is asking to select the spans with ids containing "phone" as long as they are not contained in a div with class "referencePhones." All of the solutions that use parent() return the parent div and not the span.

The following selector returns the spans:

```
$('div:not(.referencePhones) span[id*="Phone"]')
```